# Binding Linq object property to combobox

Tags: vb.net, linq, combobox

I am able to bind a combobox to the property of linq object with this code (where salesOrderHeader is my linq object and CustomerId is the property):

```
cb_Customer.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", salesOrderHeader, "CustomerId"))
```

However, this only works if the property is as integer data type.

When i try the following it doesnt work as 'orderCurrencyid' is only a byte

```
cb_OrderCurrency.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", salesOrderHeader, "orderCurrencyid"))
```

How can i bind non integer values from a LINQ object to a combobox?

Comment: It depend on what items are in the `comboBox.DataSource`? You can bind `SelectedItem` to object, but ComboBox selections will work only if `DataSource` is collection of same type and contain reference to the selected item.

Comment: My combobox contains the item needed. If i do the following  and explicity set the value `cb_OrderCurrency.SelectedValue = CInt(salesOrderHeader.orderCurrencyid)` it works ok. My problem is how do  i do the converting to int bit when binding?

Comment: Why are you specifying `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i was using SelectedValue, i must have tried SelectedItem to see if it work and posted that code by mistake. To confirm, it does not work with either SelectedValue or SelectedItem. Ive updated the question.

Comment: type of property which used as `ValueMember` and type of value used for `SelectedValue` should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fabio for pointing me in the right direction.

I managed to solve this by changing my combo box items class from:

```
Public Class cbValues

    Private mItemId As Integer
    Private mItemName As String

    Public Sub New(ItemId As Integer, ItemName As String)
        mItemId = ItemId
        mItemName = ItemName
    End Sub

    Public Property ItemId As Integer
        Get
            Return mItemId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            mItemId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ItemName As String
        Get
            Return mItemName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mItemName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

To

```
Public Class cbValues

    Private mItemId As Object
    Private mItemName As String

    Public Sub New(ItemId As Object, ItemName As String)
        mItemId = ItemId
        mItemName = ItemName
    End Sub

    Public Property ItemId As Object
        Get
            Return mItemId
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            mItemId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ItemName As String
        Get
            Return mItemName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mItemName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Changing all the integer references to objects, means it will now work and bind regardless of what the data type of ItemId property is.